# Why can't I use Template Toolkit?

Tags: perl, iis, template-toolkit, activestate

I am trying to use TemplateToolkit instead of good ole' variable interpolation and my server is giving me a lot of grief.  Here are the errors I am getting:

```
*** 'D:\Inetpub\gic\source\extjs_source.plx' error message at: 2008/09/30 15:27:37 failed to create context: failed to create context: failed to load Template/Stash/XS.pm: Couldn't load Template::Stash::XS 2.20:

Can't load 'D:/Perl/site/lib/auto/Template/Stash/XS/XS.dll' for module Template::Stash::XS: load_file:The specified procedure could not be found at D:/Perl/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 230.  at D:/Perl/site/lib/Template/Stash/XS.pm line 31

BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at D:/Perl/site/lib/Template/Stash/XS.pm line 31. Compilation failed in require at D:/Perl/site/lib/Template/Config.pm line 82.
```

The Platform is Windows Server 2003 and we are using ActiveState perl and PPM for the packages with IIS.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I figured this one out after a long time.  Apparently the ActiveState people didn't check much into the package because it requires Template::Stash::XS, but that's not actually available in PPM.  To fix this issue just edit the Template/Config.pm and change Template::Stash::XS to Template::Stash.

Comment: Not sure when this was fixed, but the current Template-Toolkit via ppm works fine with ActivePerl 5.10.1.1006.

Answer (score 4):

From what I hear, if Template Toolkit is available for Strawberry Perl, you should definitely look into switching to Strawberry.

Comment: I'd love to, but being in the lower echelons of decision making I don't know if now is the time :-)